# Emacs Lisp: suppress "Saving file" text while running ELisp file from shell

Tags: elisp

To start my Emacs Lisp script from shell, I use this command:

```
emacs --script my-script.el -f my-function
```

In my script I save 3 buffers to 3 files.
And it's working OK. But when script is running on the shell it prints the text:

```
Using vacuous schema

Saving file "some-file-to-save"

Wrote "some-file-to-save"
```

This text prints 3 times. How I can suppress this text?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know offhand how to fix it "properly" in ELisp, but an easy solution would be to just discard output:

```
emacs --script my-script.el -f my-function > /dev/null
```

This tells the shell to send all of stdout to `/dev/null` (which discards all data written to it). Obviously this requires a) an operating system that has `/dev/null` (i.e. most Unices, including macOS) and b) a shell that doesn't suck (i.e. not `cmd.exe`).

Comment: It's not help because in my script I use "interactive" mode and user need to input some data to start my-script. Also I need to print some help text like "start script", "finish script".

Comment: @Alexei gotcha. hopefully someone else will come along who's better equipped to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the function calls that dumps these messages in your script.

Assuming that the first message comes from the function `save-buffer` which calls the function `message` (files.el), just override the behavior of `message` by replacing, in your script, the invocation of `save-buffer` (or whoever is called) by:

```
(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message) #'ignore))
  (save-buffer))
```

Your need to add

```
(require 'cl-lib)
```

on top of your script if not already there.